# Understanding Maven dependencies and assembly

Tags: java, maven

I am not very much experienced with Maven and it's compilation and packaging logic gets me confused.

I have some dependencies declares as :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.dependency_group</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency_1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.dependency_group</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency_2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So as far as I understand, `dependency_1` will be added to the classpath of my program as something that comes along with my jar, and `dependency_2` on the other hand, will be added to the classpath as something that the system runtime will provide upon deployment.

Then I run the `package` goal of Maven and none of my dependencies are packed with my code (I am using the `shade` plugin, but even without it nothing changes).

I expected that when some dependency is set as `compile` `scope`, it will be exported with my compiled code, since AFAICS, there's no point in setting the classpath saying a dependency will come along with my code, and Maven just don't package that dependency with it. It looks to me as if Maven is not obeying it's contract.

So:

1 - What's the logic behind this?

2 - Do I have to always use the Assembly plugin?

3 - Are there cases where people will define a dependency as `compile` and will not want it packaged within a `jar`?

Answer (score 2):

Let me shed some light on the main point here. There are fundamentally two kinds of java artifacts:

1. Applications, i.e. ears, wars, executable jars
2. Libraries, i.e. jars that are meant to be used as dependencies for other artifacts.

For Applications your reasoning makes perfectly sense. Wars and Ears automatically package all their compile dependencies and you need no assembly plugin for that. For libraries, you do not pack the dependencies into the library. Maven handles transitive dependency resolution and would be confused if you put a fat jar on the classpath.

The thing is that packaging `jar` can be both a libary or an application. If you want a standalone application, you need to tell Maven to package everything, e.g. by using the assembly plugin or shade plugin.

Comment: Oh that makes lots of sense... So Maven could make things easier and have an option to say if the jar is an executable or a library, so we could avoid the hassle to use the Assembly plug-in

Answer (score 0):

You use `compile` scope when you want some dependencies to come along with your code. For example you want `Jackson` to be a part of your application if you are using it for json serialization.

You use `provided` scope, if you want dependency to be on the classpath during the compilation but wont be included within your application. It must be provided by running environment. For example you want `Lombok` as it is compile only library, or you want to have `Servlet Api` dependency as provided when you are writing servlet application because such app will be ran on servlet container thus there is no need to pack it within your application (it will be available in container runtime)

> Do I have to always use the Assembly plugin

Nobody forces you to do so.

Comment: The way you explain it is how I understood...that if something is declared as `compile` so it will come along with my `jar`. But currently I am generating a jar, with `compile` `scope` on all my dependencies, and NONE of them in being exported with my `jar`, which triggers a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when I run my code. So AFAICS I need to add the `Assembly plugin` in order to get my dependencies in my `jar`, am I wrong?

Comment: It dependes on how are you building your jar. It should be done like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven. OFC you have to use assembly plug (or others) for that. Including dependencies is not java compiler's feature. If we talk about javac purely, then tjhis scope has the same affect - including dependenci on **compilers classpath**

Comment: Well, I understand that's not the compiler's job... But I thought it was Maven's job

Comment: So why aren't my depencies into my jar? Lol

Comment: But maven is nothing by itself but a plugin container roughtly speaking. Everything is done by plugins - ye even compilation is done by compiler plugin. I have no clue what is your problem here.

Comment: *So why aren't my depencies into my jar? Lo* idk, you are not telling Maven to do it - simple.

Comment: Well, I guess I expected it to have a default (overridable) behavior, including those plug-ins... So I wouldn't have to include the Assembly plug-in every time I wanted to export my depencies with my jar

Comment: Your expectations are wrong here. That's it i guess.

Comment: Well, I could bet I never used the Assembly plug-in before, I will check some old code of mine to figure this out, thanks

Comment: Why would it be as default? Why do you think that everybody wants to do it as you do? What about plugins, servlets, all other stuff that strictly requires to NOT TO create fat jar. Actlually, there are more usecases for slimjars than fat jars. So i guess that is the default here - compile only.

Comment: Well, I thought that if I declared `package` to `jar` and some depencies scope as `compile` and others as `provided`, so the ones declared as `compile` would be exported within the jar... I can't see why someone will declare something as `compile` and NOT wanting it into the jar

Comment: `package` is only a phase. Besides you got all the classes packaged into jar right ?? FYI jar creation is not compilers feature neither.

Comment: I thought if people wanted small jars, just declare everything as `provided`

Comment: And here is where your problem lies. Besides fat jar is only 1 of packaging method. You can make assembly to create jar + lib directory for example. So again - why would fj be the default ?? ;)

Comment: I see... Well, in my case I would like a lib folder inside a uber jar...so I guess I have plenty of reading to do...

Comment: I have provided you the link onto how to configura assembly to create fatjar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven.

Comment: Lib dir inside jar? I don't think thats possible due to how JVM is looking up classes from jar. Directory structure must reflect packages. Assembly will repack your classes into single jar.

Comment: Well, I need an uber jar (shade plug-in) to deploy into AWS lambda... One of their recommendations for making Java more efficient is to package the libs into a lib folder, so the whole thing isn't processed into the classpath in the first run

Comment: but lib dir is not part of jar. And that is what I wrote lilbit earlier that it is possible do do jar + lib dir.

Comment: AFAIK the jar is just a zip... So I thought this made sense, the JVM would unzip the jar and the lib folder will be there.... But I am really not sure about this

Comment: No this does not make any sense. JVM does not unpack it. The fact that jars are zips is meaningless

Comment: Hmm... So maybe there are referring to making a zip of lib folder + jar.... I will revisit this into their documentation

Comment: Yep that is most probably what they mean.